# Сгруппировать все значения в выборке кроме NULL MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне нужно построить SQL запрос так, чтобы я с таблицы получал сгруппированные значения по stand_server_id, но не сгруппированные по NULL.

Например (закрашенные нужно не добавлять в выборку):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица:

[image: Таблица]

Comment: Ну и чего можно сделать со скриншотами? замените на CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, и дайте требуемый результат для именно таких данных. *сгруппированные значения по stand_server_id, но не сгруппированные по NULL* `GROUP BY COALESCE(stand_server_id, RAND())`

Comment: @Akina вместо rand() думаю лучше будет взять stand_unit_id, он уникален по определению. Можно к нему что то добавить, что бы с stand_server_id не пересекся. Я понимаю, что возможность повторения rand() исчезающе мала, но она есть

Comment: @Mike Да, разумно. Впрочем, я как бы дал общее решение (даже скорее подход к нему).

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял, что вам нужно, то можно объединить запрос с группировкой и запрос с выборкой по NULL через UNION:

```
SELECT stand_unit_id, stand_id, stand_server_id from stand_units where stand_server_id is null
UNION ALL
SELECT MIN(stand_unit_id), stand_id, stand_server_id from stand_units where stand_server_id is not null group by stand_id, stand_server_id
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В выборке по каким то причинам дублируется 1 запись

Comment: where 2-го запроса потерялось, исправил

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает!)